# Probability to trigger X from a 2% chance being instantly rolled 5 times

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out the probability of a certain mechanic happening in a game I play.

- There is a 2% chance to trigger event X on every spell cast I do
- I have an individual cast that counts as 5 spells
- These are not separate events this is 5 possible 2% chances happening instantaneously

What is the probability of event X being triggered from a 2% chance being instantly rolled 5 times.

This is a 2% chance to trigger event X being rolled 5 times but is this additive? Is the probability 10%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that event X can only be triggered once in the combined cast no matter how many spells trigger individually. Then the probability that *no* spells trigger X in the combined case is $(1-2\%)^5=0.9039$. Its complement is $0.0961=9.61\%$.

With small probabilities like 2% and small numbers of repetitions like five, simply adding them is not exactly correct, but will be close.

Comment: Thanks I understand it now; though isn't it 9.61% and not 10.61%?

Comment: @Analog Yes, you got me; corrected.